# What should our site be called, and what should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name diy.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

What should our site be called, and what should our domain name be?

Please only post names that are available or willing to be sold for a reasonable amount of money. Please also take the tips from the official blog post into consideration: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/

One suggestion per answer, please.

Here is a list of punny words that might make for a catchy diy name:

- Nail - also means to do something perfectly "I nailed it"
- Drive - also seems to have determination "he's got a lot of drive"
- home - also means a target "he hammered the point home"
- measured - also means reasoned or well thought out "he used a measured approach to cooking"
- hammer - also means to emphasize "hammer a point home"
- hit the nail on the head - illustrate or understand a concept perfectly

Comment: Please make this CW. Also, we need to make sure each domain is available

Comment: I think it is worth suggesting a name even if its .com domain is taken.  It may inspire someone to come up with a good, available variation.

Comment: I don't suggest posting taken names. It adds a whole bunch of noise.

Comment: I'm thinking some of the best names are going to be squatted.  $5k for a good name is *much* better than $0 for a bad one.  If this site is a real business proposition, I think squatted names should be considered.  If it's just for fun, then the name doesn't really matter!?

Answer (score 11):

**TwiceMeasured.com**

Available. So is MeasuredTwice, but MeasureTwice is taken and the names sound too similar, especially with the dt sound.

Answer (score 6):

**levelbubble.com**

It's a beautiful thing isn't it?

Available.

Answer (score 5):

**MeasuredAdvice.com**

Available, but might be too unoriginal considering the cooking SE is leaning towered SeasonedAdvice.com

Comment: I quite like this one though.

Answer (score 5):

## [sinkoverflow.com](http://sinkoverflow.com)

Similar to "Stack Overflow", which is a plus for brand recognition. And unlike "Math Overflow", a sink overflow is a real thing:

[image]

As the owner of the domain, I'll donate it to the site if it gets chosen.

Comment: Not bad, I like it, but sounds too much like plumbing-related, not general DIY.

Answer (score 3):

**ToiletOverflow** in homage to StackOverflow.

A toilet overflow is also a real thing. Pictures not included for the more sensitive among us.

Comment: I know something-broken names are being discouraged, but I like this!

Answer (score 2):

**HammerMeetsThumb.com**

Available.

Comment: The powers-that-be from SE are trying to avoid "negative" names if possible. I can't find the link to the post though.

Comment: @Farseeker: StackOverFlow and ServerFault are quite negative…

Comment: see Robert's comment on http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-our-site-be-called-and-what-should-our-domain-name-be/81#81

Answer (score 2):

**HammeredHome.com**

Available.

Comment: How about HammeredHomeOwner.com?

Comment: @JohnFx - "Hammered" as in drowning one's sorrows at the state of their house? :)

Answer (score 2):

BuildersUnite.com is available

It combines the theme and the community aspect.  It might also cater to pros?

Comment: One domain per answer please.

Comment: Sounds like a union.

Answer (score 0):

hereIhangmyhammer.com

Answer (score 0):

### weDIY.com

And I needed 13 characters...

Answer (score -1):

#### HouseBroken.com

Taken.

Answer (score -1):

**diyfaq.com**

[*Currently being squatted*](http://diyfaq.com/)

Answer (score -1):

**ToolboxOverflow.com**
Available.

Answer (score -1):

Wise DIY

## WiseDIY.com

Available.

Answer (score -1):

**crackedboard.com**

Available. I like keeping the pattern from stackoverflow and serverfault.

Comment: The powers-that-be from SE are trying to avoid "negative" names if possible. I can't find the link to the post though.

Comment: It's from the blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/. There's nothing necessarily *wrong* with such names. We're just urging users not to over-focus on past conventions. Quote: *"Please don’t think that it’s necessary to use a domain name that reflects something going wrong. We picked the name 'Stack Overflow' because it has some meaning for real programmers, not because it reflected a bug or problem. I get depressed by all these suggestions of 'BurntChicken.com', 'LostYarmulke.com', and 'FallenArches.com' (for former owners of McDonald’s franchises, of course)."*

Answer (score -1):

**PlungeAndFlush.com**

Available.

Answer (score -1):

**IsItOffYet.com**

Available.

Answer (score -1):

How about TwoRightThumbs.com?

Answer (score -1):

idoitmyself.com

Comment: looks too much like "Idiot Myself".

Comment: It's amazing what you don't see when you first look at something. I guess that's why the collaborative power of the SO model works so well here.

Comment: And we all know what the community thinks about hyphenating.

Answer (score -2):

**10thumbs.com**

Taken by squatter, for sale.

Answer (score -2):

**HammerTime.com**

Taken.

Answer (score -3):

#### HoneyDoList.com

Taken.