# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-our-site-be-called-and-what-should-our-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Answer (score 3):

### Tagline

I tried and failed to come up with a word play for "conquered", as in:

> I framed, I sawed, I...

With thanks to [@Steve Jackson](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/517/steve-jackson), the missing word could be "lacquered" or "contoured".

Comment: +1 for either, but I'd choose "contoured"

Answer (score 3):

**Tagline**
Taking the Y out of DIY.

Answer (score 1):

Between *doing it all alone* and *hiring someone else* is DIY.se: we'll help you get your projects done.

(elevator pitch)

Answer (score 1):

### Motto

> Your home, enhanced.

Or maybe just "Home, enhanced"; thoughts?

Comment: For some reason, my mind associated this with spam: "Add inches to your home with this simple pill!"

Comment: Maybe I just have a dirty mind.

Answer (score 1):

### Tagline

> DIY with a little help from your friends.

Answer (score 1):

#### Motto

```
Can you fix it! Yes you can!
```

along the lines of **bob the builder** :-)

Comment: +1 By far my favorite theme song of all the kiddie shows.

Comment: should it be "Can you fix it?" with a "?" instead of a "!" ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I split this post into separate posts per the request in [@yhw42's](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/531/yhw42) comment.  If you feel inclined to vote, please vote on them instead.

### Taglines...

- Helping you build your better home
- DIY with a little help from your friends (now get that tune out of your head!)

I tried and failed to come up with a word play for "conquered", as in "I framed, I sawed, I... ".  Too esoteric?

### Mottos...

- Your home, enhanced.

Comment: I framed, I sawed, I...lacquered?  contoured?

Comment: These are all good!  I've been thinking on it off and on since the weekend.  I really want to see the site succeed.

Comment: can you break these each into their own answer so they can be voted on seperately?

Comment: Rep doesn't matter in meta (I think?) so I'm downvoting this just to surface your separated answers.

Comment: @SteveArmstrong: Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Tagline

> Helping you build your better home.